# erro getline não lê o arquivo

Tags: c++

estou tentando fazer um programa que armazene alguns dados e depois mostre no formato ( matricula , nome, nota1, nota2, ) mas quando executo o código o programa não lê o arquivo txt e mostra  uma outra parte código que ja passou. No cmd ele fica assim [![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]]

tenho que usar alguma função especifica pra mostrar os resultados?

```
 #include <fstream>

 using namespace std;

 int main() {

 std::fstream arquivo;
 int n , nota1, nota2, matricula;
 string  linha , opcao ("opcao: ") , nome ;

 cout << " 0 - sair \n 1 - criar arquivo \n 2 - incluir registros no arquivo \n 3 - mostrar arquivos \n \n" ;
 cout << opcao  ;
 cin >>  n ;

 while (n!= 0 ){
 if (n==1){
 arquivo.open ("C:\\Users\\dougl\\Documents\\teste\\teste.txt");
 cout << "\n\n arquivo criado corretamente\n \n \n ";
 cout << "0 - sair \n 1 - criar arquivo \n 2 - incluir registros no arquivo \n 3 - mostrar arquivos \n \n" << "\n" << opcao ;
 cin >> n ;
 }

 if(n==2) {
 cout << "matricula: " ;
 cin >> matricula   ;
 cout << "nome: " ;
 cin  >>   nome  ;
 cout << "nota 1: " ;
 cin >> nota1 ;
 cout << "nota 2: " ;
 cin >> nota2 ;
 arquivo << "matricula: // nome: // nota1: // nota2: " << matricula  << nome << nota1 << nota2;
 cout << "\n\n";
 arquivo.close();
 cout << " 0 - sair \n 1 - criar arquivo \n 2 - incluir registros no arquivo \n 3 - mostrar arquivos \n \n" <<  opcao ;
 cin >> n;
 }

 if (n== 3) {
 arquivo.open ("C:\\Users\\dougl\\Documents\\teste\\teste.txt",std::ifstream::in);

 if (arquivo.is_open())
 {
 while(getline(arquivo,linha))
 {
 cout << linha << endl ;
 }
 }else {
 cout << "\n erro no arquivo" ;
 }

 }}
 if (n==0){

 return 0;
 }
 }
```

o erro acontece no

````
 arquivo.open ("C:\\Users\\dougl\\Documents\\teste\\teste.txt",std::ifstream::in);

 if (arquivo.is_open())
 {
 while(getline(arquivo,linha))
 {
 cout << linha << endl ;
 }
 }else {
 cout << "\n erro no arquivo" ;
 } ```
````

Comment: Aqui: `if(n=1) {` você está atribuindo 1 à variável `n`. Se quiser comparar com 1 utilize: `if(n==1) {`. Idem demais `if`s.

Comment: eu atualizes os ifs , mas agora no if (n=3) começa um loop spamando erro no arquivo, não entendi o porque de não abrir o txt

Comment: Você fecha o arquivo após incluir um único registro. Se tentar incluir um segundo registro o arquivo estará fechado. É isso mesmo?

Comment: seria um programa pra incluir mais de um registro, seria mais ou menos assim: matricula, nome , nota1  e nota2, e fecha, dps editando o mesmo arquivo colocando outra pessoa